# How can I convert different numeric vector type in C++

Tags: c++, stl

My question is related to numeric type conversion in C++. A very common way to do that is to use static_cast, for example:

```
float a;
int b;
a = 3.14;
b = static_cast<int>(a);
```

Then, how about numeric vector type conversion? Could we continue to use static_cast? I have done the following experiment:

```
typedef vector<int> IntVector;
typedef vector<float> FloatVector;
IntVector myvector;
myvector.push_back(3);
myvector.push_back(4);
myvector.push_back(5);

// Solution 1 (successful)
FloatVector solution1 ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );
for(int i=0; i<solution1.size(); i++)
   cout<<solution1[i]<<endl;
// Solution 2 (failed)
FloatVector solution2;
solution2 = static_cast<FloatVector> (myvector);
```

It seems that for numeric vector types it is impossible to use static_cast to convert. I was wondering whether there are good solutions to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: solution 1 looks good to me, why are you unhappy with it?

Comment: @john The reason why I am not satisfied with solution1 is as follows: suppose the input parameter of a function is FloatVector, however, the variable I have is of FloatInt type; in order to invoke the function, I have to create a FloatVector first and then invoke the function. I was curios whether I can use a elegant way to put FloatInt variable in the function directly, like static_cast.

Comment: @feelfree: Even if static_cast worked in this case all it would be doing is creating a FloatVector 'behind the scenes'. If you want automatic conversion of complex types the way to do it is to declare the appropiate constructors. For instance `class FloatVector { public: explicit FloatVector(const FloatInt& x); ... };` Now static_cast will convert a FloatInt to a FloatVector, if you drop the explicit then you won't even need static_cast. But there is no way to do this with typedef's, you need proper classes.

Comment: @feelfree you can pass a temporary to the function. In any case, in your `static_cast` example, you still have to create a `FloatVector`.

Comment: @jonhn Thanks, and I made a mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language directly supports conversion from one numeric type to another. You do not even need the `static_cast`, you could just assign. This conversion involves a logical copying of the value, as opposed to a reinterpretation of the value representation.

The language does not directly support conversion between arrays of different types, or for that matter of `std::vector` of different types.

But as you found, there is some support for copying elements, and then when each element is numeric, the built-in support for numeric type conversion kicks in for each element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::copy](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html), as it performs sequential assignement.

Comment: But this is no improvement compared to the two-iterator construction of a `FloatVector`.

Comment: @juanchopanza not true - you can only construct a vector once, while you can copy into it many times. This means you can create a FloatVector and then copy different IntVectors in it.

Comment: But in the context of the question, the ability to do this offers no improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You can neither assign nor cast a container with a template parameter `T` (`std::vector<int>`) into another with a template parameter `L` (`std::vector<float>`). They are different classes after all.

<strike>However, since they use iterators you can fill your `FloatVector` with [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):</strike>

```
FloatVector solution2(myvector.size());

std::copy(myvector.begin(),myvector.end(),solution2.begin());
```

**Edit** to [address your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773841/how-can-i-convert-different-numeric-vector-type-in-c/11773944#comment15636352_11773841):

If your current function signature is `f(FloatVector)` I would recommend you to change it to

```
template< class T >
ReturnType f(std::vector<T> myVector, ....);
```

Comment: But this is no improvement compared to the two-iterator construction of a `FloatVector`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Oops, I didn't notice, thanks. I misread his for-loop as an assignment instead of calls to `cout`. I guess it's time for coffee.